# Wordpress custom post type permalink: website.com/post-name/post-id

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am trying to build a custom permalink in wordpress for my custom post type `artikelen` (exact slug). I found code online and it seems to do the work with transforming the links with a custom structure `%postname%/%postid%`, but when I save my permalinks and go to a detail page I get a 404 error.

I am posting my code to demonstrate my way of working.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 3);

function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'artikelen' ){
        return home_url( $post->post_name .'/'. $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );

function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'product/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=artikelen&p=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
product/([0-9]+)?$
```

[translates to](https://regex101.com/r/RHTMmw/2) `product/` followed by any number or nothing (and nothing more, not even a trailing slash). This doesn't sound like the thing you want to achieve.

Instead, try the following

```
function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=artikelen&p=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

which [translates to](https://regex101.com/r/RHTMmw/3):

- `^` start of the string (ie, there is nothing else in front)
- `([^/]+)`: at least one character that is not `/`
- `/`: a slash
- `([0-9]+)`: at least one number
- `/?`: zero or one (trailing) slash
- `$`: end of the string